# Looking for a WIF implementation for SAML 2.0

Tags: .net, wif, saml-2.0

Is there an implementation in WIF (Windows Identity Foundation) for SAML 2.0 SP (Service Provider)?

I read many [articles](http://www.idmcrisis.com/post/2011/05/16/Finally!!!-SAML2-for-WIF.aspx) and [announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-the-wif-extension-for-saml-2-0-protocol-community-technology-preview.aspx) that WIF supports SAML-P but could not find yet a full implementation!

I found many open source toolkits on the internet but could not run them on Windows Azure AD as a SAML IdP.

I'm looking for an implementation from Microsoft and I don't want to use the WS-Federation because I should support SAML 2.0.

Comment: Do you mean the ASML-p protocol ?  wif supports Salm 2.0 tokens.

Answer (score 1):

There is no SAML protocol implementation from Microsoft in WIF. There is ADFS (all internal classes), but no WIF only. SAML Token (assertion) is there in WIF, but the SAML2 Message level is missing completely. There has been a Beta from Microsoft. Production with the beta is not allowed and it has been silent for years now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now, is there any implementation for an SP consuming ADFS / SAML tokens ?

Answer (score 1):

As per @paullem, there is no current WIF implementation of SAML-P (the protocol).

Look [here](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html) for some suggestions (especially the top link).

You mention that you want WIF for a SP but then you say that you can't run in AAD as a IDP?

Would exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, I wanna implement an SP SAML enable with the ability to connect to Azure AD. 

The open source toolkits existing on the internet did not work with Azure AD

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now, is there any implementation for an SP consuming ADFS / SAML tokens ?

Comment: Yes - pretty much all the products in the link above provide client-side SAML support. (BTW WIF also consumes SAML tokens!

Comment: I've tested OneLogin. It was the simplest. It worked fine with their IdP but not with ADFS. And I did not find an implementation or a sample online for consuming ADFS as an IdP.